# Saving JSON file to iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, json

I want save json file from server each time, when user have internet connection to use it when iPhone doesnt have internet connection. But it doesn't working. Here is my code:

```
- (void)writeJsonToFile
{
    //applications Documents dirctory path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    //live json data url
    NSString *stringURL = @"http://volodko.info/ic/json.php";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    //attempt to download live data
    if (urlData)
    {
        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"data.json"];
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }
    //copy data from initial package into the applications Documents folder
    else
    {
        //file to write to
        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"data.json"];

        //file to copy from
        NSString *json = [ [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"json" inDirectory:@"html/data" ];
        NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:json options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        //write file to device
        [jsonData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean by not working ?

Comment: Did you tried using Core Data for your need..?

Comment: App crash without internet, but must use local json file

Answer (score 2):

try this . . .

```
- (void)writeJsonToFile
{
    //applications Documents dirctory path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    //live json data url
    NSString *stringURL = @"http://volodko.info/ic/json.php";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    //attempt to download live data
    if (urlData)
    {
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.json"];
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }
    //copy data from initial package into the applications Documents folder
    else
    {
        //file to write to
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.json"];;

        //file to copy from
        NSString *json = [ [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"json" inDirectory:@"html/data" ];
        NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:json options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        //write file to device
        [jsonData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. Read the AFJSONRequestOperation guide. The code also checks if the json-file already have been cached.

```
NSString *path = @"http://volodko.info/ic/json.php";
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    id cachedJson = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:path];
    if (cachedJson) {
        [self didUpdateJSON:cachedJson];
    } else {
        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
            [self didUpdateJSON:JSON];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:JSON forKey:path];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            });
        } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
            NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
        }];
        [operation start];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Fetch data from JSON parser and store it in an array. After that you can add it to a SQLite database.

Answer (score 0):

You should create path in proper way

replace this

```
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"data.json"];
```

with

```
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.json"];
```

Comment: Not working :( Here is console data: 2013-12-12 14:30:54.420 iPhoneCenter[301:1503] Network connection failed. Making attempt 4 after sleeping for 6.849714 seconds.
2013-12-12 14:31:13.962 iPhoneCenter[301:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

Comment: then check whether data is there or not? I given solution to make proper path. First check whether data downloaded from WerbService or not. If(data.length>0) then only write to path.

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSUserDefaults instead of writing this small JSON text to a file

```
- (void)writeJsonToFile
{
    NSString *jsonString;

    NSString *stringURL = @"http://volodko.info/ic/json.php";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    if (urlData)
    {
        // JSON successfully downloaded, store it to user defaults
        jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:jsonString forKey:@"jsonString"];
    }
    else
    {
        // no urlData, using stored JSON
        jsonString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"jsonString"];
    }
}
```

possibly even better:

```
- (NSString *)getJSON
{
    <the code above>
    return jsonString;
}
```

and then use it in other functions as:

```
NSString *jsonString = [self getJSON];
```

Answer (score 0):

Anton , fetch the `json` data and store in the `nsmutable array` at the first time you Array hold the data when u run again ur array not a nil but replay the data to the second time ... and another way to store the data in `local database`...if u r needed to store the data..

but ur problem is solve for first one..ok best of luck..